# NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass when attempting to delete an object from a database via the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

lAs I attempt to create a simple Rails project. I have this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

I am simply creating a database with movies that I am manually inputting.

I have migrated the following:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.decimal :total_gross
      t.date :release_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I added data to my db. I instantiate an object to a variable. I am attempting delete the particular movie that I have on my database. I have tried to use the destroy and delete method, but the error shows.

```
2.0.0-p247 :025 > puss_boots = Movie.find_by(title: 'Puss and boots')
  Movie Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."title" = 'Puss and boots' LIMIT 1
 => nil
2.0.0-p247 :026 > puss_boots.destroy
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):26
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p247 :027 > puss_boots.delete
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):27
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You're not finding a matching movie. See the response to line 025: It's `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving that error because there was no record returned for that query:

`Movie.find_by(title: 'Puss and boots')`

You want to confirm that your record was loaded before calling destroy.

Also take note of the console output between your calls. The first call:
`puss_boots = Movie.find_by(title: 'Puss and boots')` 
makes a `SELECT` query on your Movie table and returns nil, which simply means that no record was found for that query.

Comment: I consider myself a rookie so I can empathize. In my rookie opinion, the most valuable takeaway I've realized in learning this wonderful language is to pay attention to EXACTLY what the console is outputting. It may seem like gibberish but is actually very telling... Best wishes!